# Strange behavior with compile error "expected specifier-qualifier list before 'CustomClass'"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have been having some trouble lately with using custom classes as types. As described in the title, I have been getting compile errors similar to the one below:

```
expected specifier-qualifier list before 'MyClass'
```

My code is usually something along the lines of this:

```
@interface MyCoolClass : NSObject {
    MyClass *myClassObject; // Error is on this line.
}
```

I also occasionally use something like this:

```
@interface MyCoolClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet MyClass *myClassObject; // Error again on this line
}
```

Im not really sure if that is good to use but on occasion, I have done something like that so I could connect my objects together with Interface Builder so that one object could invoke a method on another object.

I've been able to do this before successfully with other projects but when I tried to do it today, it gave me this error. Any ideas what could be causing it? As far as I can tell, I have done the same thing that I did in the other project here.

It is also to my understanding that this error usually gets thrown if the type is not defined, but I am pretty sure that I have defined it.

Comment: Post the content of `MyClass.h`!

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, I wasn't really paying attention to what I was typing. The code I posted would be the content of MyClass.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, GCC how obtuse and opaque can your errors possibly be....

Try compiling with the LLVM 2.0 compiler.  It'll give you much more sane errors.

In this case, what is *usually* going on is that the compiler doesn't have a clue what `MyClass` is *or* there is a syntax error in the previously included header file that doesn't cause a compilation error until the @interface is hit in the file spewing the error.

It could also be a misspelling.

---

Or, as suggested, you need to #import "MyClass.h" into the header file (or implementation file or, even better, the PCH file) so that MyClass is defined before the iVar declaration.

```
@class MyClass;
```

That'll also do the trick.

Comment: In any case, if you're just using the class as an ivar, you should be using `@class` in the header.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I switched my compiler to LLVM and, as you said, it did give a more comprehensive error:

Unknown type name 'MyClass'

I've checked through my code to see if there were any spelling mistakes or other code-related mistakes and I found nothing. For a temporary fix, I changed my types to "id" and this compiled without errors and works fine. Any more suggestions? I can just use "id" but I would like to know what I might be doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Jesse, almost certainly you are forgetting to either `#import "MyClass.h"` or `@class MyClass;` before you reference the class name.

Comment: The question is answered (or at least it should be) - just add the `@class MyClass;` in the header before the `@interface`.  That should do it.  Also be sure to `#import "MyClass.h"` in your .m file unless you like warnings.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I added the @class at the top and that worked. I suppose that declares it so that the compiler knows it is a type? Anyway, thank you all again.